# Zakat on salary not received

Tags: zakat

I work in a foreign country and receive salary by cheque. For the past 10 months I am in my home country and haven't received salary as there are some visa issues. So once visa issue is solved, I will go there and receive those cheques which are due.

Do I have to pay zakat on that salary?

Comment: Zakat is paid on savings which you have for one lunar year. If you receive the salary before one year is complete and spend it all, then you will not have to pay zakat on it. If you receive it after an year then there are different madhabs on whether zakat is due on a receivable, see https://islamqa.info/en/answers/125854/ Also salaries are usually given on a monthly basis. So even if you get the money after an year, and have to pay Zakat according to your madhab, then you will only pay Zakat on the salary for those months which have matured for an year, and not on the whole amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general principle with zakat is that it is due on ones assets after they have been in ones possession for one year.

To my understanding, insofar as you have not yet *received* payment and have no means to access or utilize these assets, it is not considered in your possession and therefore no zakat is due on it.